# Why is this val, not a val?

Tags: java, kotlin

This one seems to be dependant on an interaction between Java and Kotlin, first a Java class:

```
public class MyJavaClass {
    private Runnable q;

    public void setRunnable(final Runnable listener) {
        q = listener;
    }

    public boolean testContains(final Runnable listener) {
        return q == listener;
    }
}
```

Now Kotlin tests:

```
class JavaInteractionTests {

    @Test
    fun `anonymous`() {
        val abc = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {

            }
        }

        val x = MyJavaClass()

        x.setRunnable(abc)
        assertTrue(x.testContains(abc))
    }

    @Test
    fun `lambda`() {
        val abc = Runnable { }

        val x = MyJavaClass()

        x.setRunnable(abc)
        assertTrue(x.testContains(abc))
    }

    @Test
    fun `function`() {
        val abc: () -> Unit = {}

        val x = MyJavaClass()

        x.setRunnable(abc)
        assertTrue(x.testContains(abc))
    }

}
```

The last test fails, so it would appear my `val` isn't actually a `val`.

Bug or explainable, expected behaviour?

Note, that if the Java class is defined in Kotlin like so, the last test does not compile:

```
class MyKtClass {
    private var q: Runnable? = null

    fun setRunnable(listener: Runnable) {
        q = listener
    }

    fun testContains(listener: Runnable): Boolean {
        return q === listener
    }
}
```

(I noticed all this when registering a callback with a Java class, going to remove it later and it failed to be removed. The callback was defined in the 3rd test style)

Comment: because it's a .JAR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that, each time when you call a Java function that accepts a `Runnable` and pass a Kotlin function `() -> Unit` into it, a `Runnable` is implicitly created that wraps the function.

And when you do that twice (`x.setRunnable(abc)` and `x.testContains(abc)`), these are two different `Runnable`s that are not equal to each other, hence the failure.

This is how [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) works in Kotlin. Basically, these calls are equivalent to

```
val abc: () -> Unit = {}

val x = MyJavaClass()

x.setRunnable(Runnable(abc)) // one Runnable
assertTrue(x.testContains(Runnable(abc))) // another Runnable
```

Also, [Kotlin does not support SAM conversions for functions that are defined in Kotlin](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770), that's why your test does not compile when you re-write the class in Kotlin. The reasoning is that Kotlin already has functional types, and they should be used instead of SAM interfaces. So, the SAM conversion is rather a mean of Java interop than a complete language feature.

Comment: So Kotlin will silently wrap this, but I have to explicitly cast ints to longs etc?!

Comment: @weston, yes, that's right. This is how SAM conversion works in Kotlin (see the link to the docs I added).

Comment: How does Kotlin recognize that a function is written in Java? Let's say you pull in some library with a function taking a SAM type. How is it decided whether the SAM conversion compile or not?

Comment: @marstran, it does not recognize that it's written *in Java*, it only finds that it's *not written in Kotlin*. There are two possible cases: when the Kotlin code belongs to the current project, and when you use a Kotlin library. In the first case, the compiler is passed Kotlin sources, not classes, so they are, evidently, written in Kotlin. In the second case, when you have a JAR with classes, the compiler tries to find the Kotlin metadata in the classes in that JAR (decompile one, and you will see the `@Metadata` annotation), and if there's none, it thinks that these are not Kotlin classes.

Comment: first, upvote. which means there is a risk to use *lambda* for the platform SAM types? e.g: `subscribe((Event)->Unit)` but I can't `unsubscribe(Listener)` in future.